# AJAX post not reliable, using '.then' doesn't work either

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, deferred, jquery-callback

I'm trying to create a hierarchical navigation bar, but I've come up against a few problems.

I've used a series of AJAX post methods to post the div ID information to a PHP page which then runs a loop and retrieves all the categories in a database.

This is done in four steps, first it call the top level category 1 and then top level category 2, then it runs two loops 3-9 and 10-50, these loops should retrieve up to 50 categories from the database and sort them.

The post method doesn't always work, sometimes when the page loads it's fine other times it misses some of the `<li>`'s, I expect this is because some AJAX requires one to load before it can work, so I tried to use .then and callbacks to sequence the posts, this doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var IDs = [];
    $("#menu").find("li").each(function() {
        IDs.push(this.id);
    });
    var arr = $.makeArray(IDs);
    var full_list = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        full_list = full_list + arr[i] + ' '

    }
    //INDEPENDANT CALL
    function A() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'DisplayCategories/SubCat.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'Parent': full_list
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
                    NewData = data.substr(2);
                    $(Element).after(NewData);


                }
            }).error(function() {
                alert('error');
            }).complete(function(data) {
                var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
                NewData = data.substr(2);
                $(Element).after(NewData);


            });
        }
        //INDEPENDANT CALL

    function B() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'DisplayCategories/SubCatCrafts.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'Parent': full_list
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
                NewData = data.substr(2);
                $(Element).after(NewData);


            }
        }).error(function() {
            alert('errosr');
        }).complete(function(data) {
            var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
            NewData = data.substr(2);
            $(Element).after(NewData);


        });
    }

    function C() {
        for (i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'DisplayCategories/SubCatLevelThree.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'Parent': i
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
                    NewData = data.substr(2);
                    $(Element).after(NewData);


                }
            }).error(function() {
                alert('error');
            }).complete(function(data) {
                var Element = data.slice(0, 2);
                NewData = data.substr(2);
                $(Element).after(NewData);


            });


        }
    }

    function D() {
        for (s = 11; s < 50; s++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'DisplayCategories/SubCatLevelEleven.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'Parent': s
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var Element = data.slice(0, 3);
                    NewData = data.substr(3);
                    $(Element).after(NewData);


                }
            }).error(function() {
                alert('error');
            }).complete(function(data) {
                var Element = data.slice(0, 3);
                NewData = data.substr(3);
                $(Element).after(NewData);



            });

        }
    }
    B();
    A();
    C();
    D();

});
```

You can see it live [**Here**](http://www.web-designs-uk.co.uk/DisplayCategories/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP backend isn't always returning content, but it is always returning a 200 HTTP code. This means that your success call back is also being called each time. Your success call back assumes that there's always content returned, which there isn't, and thus throws an error when it assumes "data" is an array and that "slice" can be called, stopping your execution in it's tracks. In short, you really need to fix your back end, and you should also do validation in your javascript of the data returned by  your php to ensure that the object, "data" in this case, is what you think it is.

You also may want to use a development console so that you can see all of this yourself. I'm rather fond of firebug in Firefox, but all the major browsers have one built in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this, I haven't put validation on the PHP file as I'm just making sure it works  first, however I still don't understand why it sometimes works on refreshing the page, I thought the Ajax wasn't giving the PHP loops enough time to run through, I've used ob_flush(); in the PHP loops to return all results but it's still not fully working

Comment: You misunderstand, you need validation in your javascript, in addition to fixing your PHP. You can't call an array function on an object that's not an array.